# how to solve python ilock FileNotFoundError?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, locking

so i am trying to use ilock in python as a system wide lock, but after few iterations in my code i get the following error, what might cause such an error? and how i can start solving it

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/ilock-bfe0d208735d8d5f20bb2b8abcf8bf67d696f23629b4ee2d4e7304f69063db61.lock'

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same error. Looks to me like it's a bug in the ilock library.

In short, when two `ILock` objects are created with the same unique name, they'll use the same file as the locking entity (passed to `portalocker`). They create the file (if it doesn't exist) using `open(path, 'w')` upon `ILock.__enter__`, and they call `os.unlink(path)` upon `ILock.__exit__`.

However consider the following scenario:

```
process1: ILock.__enter__  # file is created, lock acquired
process2: ILock.__enter__  # file already exists, lock pending
process1: does its thing under the lock
process1: ILock.__exit__   # file is unlinked, lock released
process2: does its thing under the lock
process2: ILock.__exit__   # Error: cannot unlink, file does not exist
```

On the surface, it could be that this can be fixed by silently allowing `unlink` to fail; or perhaps, by recreating the file as necessary after the lock has been acquired. I am not sure though if `portalocker` would behave nicely in this case.

Perhaps the easiest workaround is to simply NEVER delete the file (get rid of `os.unlink` altogether).

Comment: BTW, I see there's a similar issue opened on the library: https://github.com/symonsoft/ilock/issues/4